# postgreSQL when to use parentheses for keywords, ON vs USING( )

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, parentheses

I've noticed that it appears arbitrary (to me) when keywords will require a following parentheses. If a table is `JOIN`ed by identically named columns, you use `USING(ID)`. The alternative is ON `table1.column = table2.column`.

Why and when are parentheses required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`USING()` can be applied on a list of columns - like in `USING(id,seq)`. The comma, without the parentheses, could be the introduction of a following clause, so the parser can only safely determine the comma between `id` and `seq` as a list separator when we put the list into parentheses.

`ON`, on the other side, is always followed by a Boolean expression, which is straightforward to parse: `expression - comparison operator - expression` .